# How to display HTML string as a web page using Golang http.ResponseWriter?

Tags: http, go

I'm following along the example in Chapter 19 from *The Way to Go*.

This is the content of my `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

const AddForm = `
<form method="POST" action="/add">
URL: <input type="text" name="url">
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
`

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/add", Add)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func Add(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    url := r.FormValue("url")
    if url == "" {
        fmt.Fprint(w, AddForm)
        return
    }
    key := "Placeholder"
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "http://localhost:8080/%s", key)
}
```

According to the book and its screenshot, I should see a valid form rendered in my browser. But right now, I can only see the raw string.

I'm very new to go, so I'm not sure if the language has evolved a lot since the example was written. My go version is `go version go1.6.2 linux/amd64` and I think the book is written in 2012 with older version of go.

How do I modify it to make it render as a form in the browser? Thanks.

Comment: `AddForm` isn't a full html page, it's just the form fragment. Plus you're returning `Content-Type: text/plain`. Is there more to the example? This would never have worked wit the Go std lib.

Comment: The book is [here](https://ia800702.us.archive.org/8/items/TheWayToGo/The_Way_To_Go.pdf) and reading at Page 517. There are some other code, but definitely unrelated to html render here. The code is [here](https://sites.google.com/site/thewaytogo2012/Downhome/Topic3), in the zip file, in chapter19/goto_v1/main.go

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After reading through the doc, in current version of golang, http.ResponseWriter has a default Content-type as `text/plain`, and after manually set the content type as `text/html`, things are working as expected.

```
if url == "" {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    fmt.Fprint(w, AddForm)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTML templates it is better.  Template checks your HTML for errors too.

https://play.golang.org/p/l9bUoWC4PZ

In Execute if you used w instaed of stdout in my example the content type would automatically be set